# ¿Como convierto un array de bytes a una PublicKey?

Tags: java, array, codificación, criptografía

Quiero convertir un `array` de **bytes** a una `PublicKey`. El problema es que el `array` de **bytes** viene (o debería venir) codificado con `ECDH` y al ser clave pública **X509**. Se trata de la clave pública del DNIe. He estado probando con este código pero me devuelve:

> Detect premature EOF

justo en la línea en la que convierto:

```
Data(en hex) = 0bbe0c8f66d755020f6a2a656c1111664c745836ac7dafbde0af484bd66b1d31a0ba7da687acd0ee1b695b54ea274d495cb613e90d3277159827f54f316e5833

 public static PublicKey loadPublicKey (byte[] data) throws Exception{     
    PublicKey publicKey = KeyFactory.getInstance("EC").generatePublic(new X509EncodedKeySpec(data));}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intenta convertir el String Hexadecimal un *Byte Array* y cambiar el parametro de entrada a *String*.

```
public static byte[] HexToByteArr(String s) {
    int len = s.length();
    byte[] data = new byte[len / 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i += 2) {
        data[i / 2] = (byte) ((Character.digit(s.charAt(i), 16) << 4)
                             + Character.digit(s.charAt(i+1), 16));
    }
    return data;
}

public static PublicKey loadPublicKey(String myhex) throws Exception{   
    PublicKey  publicKey;        
    byte[] data = HexToByteArr(myhex);
    try {
        publicKey = KeyFactory.getInstance("EC").generatePublic(new X509EncodedKeySpec(data));
        return publicKey;
    } catch(InvalidKeySpecException e) {};

    throw new InvalidKeySpecException("EC DSA or RSA no compatibles");
}
```

Comment: Hola, me sale por el trow. Supuestamente el array de bytes que me pasa el DNIe es una clave codificada con ECDH pero no se como pasar a PublicKey

Comment: listo, intenta el nuevo codigo, deberia funcionar.